# Using Angular to set parent height of ng-if children

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I feel like I'm doing a number of things wrong here. I have a view with 3 states - call them intro, loading, and completed. I want each state to slide from left to right as the user progresses.

Here is the basic structure:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.triggered = '';
  
  $scope.loading = false;
  $scope.completed = false;
  
  $scope.one = function() {
    console.log('one');
    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.completed = false;   
  };
  
  $scope.two = function() {
    $scope.loading = false;
    $scope.completed = true;   
  };
  
}).directive('inheritHeight', ['$window', '$timeout', function($window, $timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {

        scope.$watch("loading", function(newV, oldV) {
          console.log(newV, elm[0]);
          $timeout(function () {
            scope.triggered = scope.triggered + 'triggered ';
            scope.height = elm[0].querySelector('.child').offsetHeight;
            console.log(elm[0].querySelector('.child'));
            console.log(elm[0].querySelector('.child').offsetHeight);
            elm.css('height', elm[0].querySelector('.child').offsetHeight + 'px');
          });
        });

      }
    };
}]);
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0; }
  .child.ng-enter, .child.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition: 800ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1) all;
    -moz-transition: 800ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1) all;
    -ms-transition: 800ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1) all;
    -o-transition: 800ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1) all;
    transition: 800ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1) all; }
  .child.ng-enter {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
    -o-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%); }
  .child.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0); }
  .child.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0); }
  .child.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%); }
    
.child-a {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
}

.child-b {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
}

.child-c {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-animate.js"></script>

<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="parent" inherit-height="">
    <div class="child child-a" ng-if="!loading && !completed">
      <button ng-click="one()">Click One</button>
    </div>
    <div class="child child-b" ng-if="loading && !completed">
      <button ng-click="two()">Click Two</button>
    </div>
    <div class="child child-c" ng-if="!loading && completed"></div>
  </div>
  <p>{{ height }}</p>
  <p>{{ triggered }}</p>
</div>
```

It doesn't seem that the parent div with the `inherit-height` directive can properly update its height when a new state comes into view, even though its within a `scope.$watch` and a `$timeout`...

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I expected querySelector to work because ng-if removes elements from the DOM, however, this didn't seem to be the case. Targeting the child element that was to transition in did the trick:

```
elm.css('height', elm[0].querySelector('.child.ng-enter').offsetHeight + 'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

Before making any things regarding to animation and css there are 2 things you need to know in advance:

#### 1. The scope for directive is different from the scope in controller.

In you example, `status.loading` point to nothing. Since you did not assign an isolated scope to `inherit-height` directive, it's scope would be the same as its parent, which is `MainCtrl` in your case. However, you never register something like `$scope.status.loading`, so the watcher is watching for nothing, that's why all the logic in your `$timeout` service doesn't work.

#### 2. The element argument in directive's link function is the element itself, not an array.

So there's no meaning to do `elm[0]`. Same goal could be achieve by something like `elm.eq(0).height()`.

#### 3. `querySelector` would only return the first element which matches

So in your case, it will always  select `child-a`, probably not what you want. It's generally also a bad practice to get the height of child elements this way. If you do need, create another directive and require it from the parent would be much better.

I would suggest you check the [angular document](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) or other tutorial for directive scope and the idea of link function before making other complicated css part.

Comment: Thanks for the response - .status.loading was copied from my original code.  The inherited scope is intentional - changing to "loading" (see above) triggers the watch function and applies the code. But querySelector is still targeting the wrong child div - there technically should only be one element for it to target given the ng-if logic

Comment: see updated code. also, elm is not the element itself, but a jqLite object. you need to use [0] to get the DOM object and call querySelector()

Comment: @romeboards Yeah you are right, when I said itself I actually means the jQLite wrapped element itself. 

So to simplify it you can achieve the same goal by `elm.eq(0).height()`